# What word would you use to describe someone speaking harshly but truthfully of someone else?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm thinking 'honestly' but I'm not sure that it's captures the harshness or criticalness of the situation. I want to describe someone who is not speaking overly critical of someone but exactly critical.

Comment: "brutally honest" is a phrase used for this; I don't know of a sw.

Answer (score 2):

How about, ***bluntly***?

To speak bluntly is to 'speak without trying to be polite or considering other people's feelings'

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/bluntly

Answer (score 1):

Speaking **directly** is to speak -

> Straightforwardly; pointedly; simply; plainly; †correctly, rightly (obs.).

[OED-3](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/53307?redirectedFrom=directly#eid)

> . . . our national elections speak **directly** and forcefully to only a tiny handful of major issues.

[Bureaucracy and the Policy Process:](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=DaMyH8LXdEQC&pg=PA41&dq=speak+directly&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi38brIx6HXAhUFWxoKHT9fCuQ4PBDoAQgqMAE#v=onepage&q=speak%20directly&f=false)

By Dennis D. Riley, Bryan E. Brophy-Baermann

Answer (score 1):

You can use the adverb **frankly** especially when the harsh truth you are speaking is from your emotive opinion.

> "Frankly, good lady, I find you repulsive!"
>
> John decided to be frank with Sam and told him that wearing a Hawaiian shirt to this occasion was not in good taste.